# Singular Chain complex of Smash Product

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, monoidal-categories, model-categories

\begin{align}
\Delta(X\wedge Y,pt)=\quad?
\end{align}

*Question:* Is there a nice way (similar to the Eilenberg-Zilber map) to compute the singular chain complex of a smash product of pointed spaces up to homotopy? Is there a version of the Eilenberg-Zilber theorem which works for pairs of spaces?

*Partial Result.* It works out in some cases. For example
\begin{align}
\Delta(S^1\wedge S^1,pt) &= \Delta(S^2,pt)\\&\simeq \mathbb Z[2]
\end{align}
and
\begin{align*}
\Delta(S^1,pt)\otimes \Delta (S^1,pt) &\simeq \mathbb Z[1]\otimes \mathbb Z[1] \\&= \mathbb Z[2]
\end{align*}
It is also the case that
\begin{align*}
\Delta(X_+\wedge Y_+,pt) \simeq \Delta(X_+,pt)\otimes \Delta(Y_+,pt)
\end{align*}
for unbased spaces $X,Y\in \mathcal T_0$.

*Motivation.* Peter May states in "More Concise Algebraic Topology" that there are a lot of analogies between the homotopy of $Ch(\mathbb Z)$ and categories of spaces. They state that since $Ch(\mathbb Z)$ has a zero object and $\mathcal T_0$ does not, the right thing to do is to compare $Ch(\mathbb Z)$ with the category of pointed spaces $\mathcal T_\ast$. So I was wondering if it is literally possible to compare $\mathcal T_\ast$ and $Ch(\mathbb Z)$ (as monoidal model categories). I have also tried to compare the smash in $sSet_\ast$ with the tensor in $Ch(\mathbb Z)$, but haven't been succesful.

Comment: Any cosmos admits a smash product and an associated pointed cosmos, with smash being the new monoidal unit. In particular, pointed chain complexes form a cosmos under the smash product. Whether that will have anything to do with the topological smash product, I couldn't say

Comment: @FShrike What are pointed chain complexes?

Comment: the monoidal action is the graded tensor product. The monoidal unit is the chain complex $\Bbb Z$ concentrated in degree zero. Therefore pointed complexes are the slice category under $\Bbb Z$. Given a complex $C_\ast$ then a point of $C_\ast$ just amounts to a choice of zero cycle

Comment: You might find the section on relative cup products in Kirk and Davis useful; in particular,  for well pointed spaces $\bar{C}_*(X \wedge Y) \simeq C_*(X \times Y, X \vee Y)$ and the latter is the target of the external relative cup product which it seems like they discuss.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question but I hope that it helps at some points. I am not sure if you can compare $\mathbf{sSet}_*$ with $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbb{Z})$ because from the point of view of Dold-Kan correspondence, the right one should be simplicial abelian groups $\mathbf{sAb}$, this category is canonically pointed by the neutral elements. Both sides of the correspondence are lax monoidal functors and are inverses (up to some equivalences) of each other, you may guess one of them is exactly the Eilenberg-Zilber map.

To understand why do you need things to be pointed, it suffices to keep in mind that we should have a good notion of homotopy groups:

- In $\mathbf{sSet}_*$, homotopy groups are really homotopy groups (of their geometric realizations).
- In $\mathbf{sAb}$ however, homotopy groups are homology groups in $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbb{Z})$ under Dold-Kan correspondence.

One last point to convince you that $\mathbf{sAb}$ is closer to $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbb{Z})$ than $\mathbf{sSet}_*$ (or $\mathbf{sSet}$) is that when you take the singular complex $\Delta(\text{something})$, you really just passed from $\mathbf{sSet}_*$ to $\mathbf{sAb}$ via the free functor (turning a set into a free abelian group) and homology groups are what come after. I am afraid that you cannot get anything in $\mathbf{sSet}_*$ from $\mathbf{sAb}$ via the free functor; even though its definition is simple but this is a mysterious functor.